# Querying Arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a Mongo collection called players and in each document there are two entries called transactions and autographs. Both are arrays with objects inside containing a timestamp.

How can I use this db.collection.count( { timestamp: {$gt: 1585526400000} }) to display how many have been inputed into the db in the last 7 days?

Comment: What are the exact conditions? Do all elements of both arrays need to have a timestamp in the last 7 days in order for a document to be counted? Maybe add input data and expected output...

Comment: So I'm wanting to query each array individually to get the total number of entries of each. They both have a timestamp as its for a game server

Comment: Hope I got it correctly - check my answer. If I got it wrong please add the expected output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following two simplified records are in your database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b8b66c1f8161eeeab762f"),
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-04-05T00:25:20.202Z")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-04-02T00:25:20.202Z")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-04-01T00:25:20.202Z")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-01-06T00:25:20.202Z")
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b9008b29982222cd38888"),
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-04-04T00:25:20.202Z")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-02-03T00:25:20.202Z")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:25:20.202Z")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-02-06T00:25:20.202Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can get the count of the array elements which your condition as follows:

```
db.getCollection('players').aggregate([{
        $project: {
            transactionsCount: {
                $size: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$transactions",
                        as: "item",
                        cond: {
                            $gte: ["$$item.timestamp", ISODate('2020-03-30 00:00:00.000Z')]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b8b66c1f8161eeeab762f"),
    "transactionsCount" : 3
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b9008b29982222cd38888"),
    "transactionsCount" : 1
}
```